# ActionBar textSize by Html.fromHtml?

Tags: android, html, text, android-actionbar

I am kind of hacking my way around to make my ActionBar the way I would like. I can't use a customview in my case, because other code will conflict. Right now I am currently displaying my ActionBar like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0069B5")));
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color = '#ffffff'>Title</font>"));
```

Is there anyway I can specify the textSize like my color and title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only specific basic html tags are recognized by `Html.fromHtml()`. You can use:

- `<small></small>`
- `<medium></medium>`
- `<large></large>`

Or you can just set the ActionBar title's font size directly:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
title.setTextSize(20); // value in sp
```

Comment: This is the way I did it.

Comment: How to set / findViewById when it is not in the XML?